# What is the concept for showing database data on several pages?

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

What is the concept for showing database data in several pages?
I have a products page. I want to show 10 products in page1. 
When I press page2 I want to show the next 10 products.
I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: That would be Pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea...

1- first in the query you need to specify the limit of records to 10 like this

```
$start=0;// im gonna talk about this later ;)
$query = "select * from yourtable litmit ".$start.",10";
//excuste your query here
```

2- next you'er gonna need to send that variable over to know each time the porevious value of the variable $start

```
//getting the variable ps : replace this line by the other one ($start=0)
$start=(isset($_GET['start']))?intval(trim($_GET['start'])):0;
```

3- now lets set the links you need , to make the link that goes to the first set of records , next and previous and last:

```
$query="select count(*) as total from yourtable";
//excute and get the total in $total
$first_link ='<a href="yourpage?start=((($start-10)<0)?0:$start-10)">Previous</a>';
$next_link ='<a href="yourpage?start='.((($start+10)>=$total)?$start:$start+10).'">Next</a>';
$first_link ='<a href="yourpage?start=0">First</a>';
$last_link ='<a href="yourpage?start='.$total.'">Last</a>';
```